# Not able to insert timestamp data in Cassandra from C program

Tags: c, cassandra, cassandra-driver

I have a simple code written in C for inserting local date and time into Cassandra's timestamp column as follows:

```
time_t rt= time(NULL);
struct tm * timeinfo;
timeinfo = localtime ( &rt );
char lt[20];
strftime(lt, sizeof(lt), "%Y-%m-%d %T", timeinfo);

 const char* query = "INSERT INTO time_table(id,time) VALUES(now(),?);";

          CassStatement* statement = cass_statement_new(query, 1);
          cass_statement_bind_string(statement,0,lt);


          CassFuture* result_future = cass_session_execute(session, statement);
```

But this code is not able to insert anything inside `time_table`. If I try to insert the same thing using cqlsh using the query `insert into time_table(id,time) values(now(),'2019-09-04 10:59:22');`, then the values are getting inserted without any problem. I am using Cassandra driver for C version 2.13.

Can anyone please point out the mistake in the code?

Comment: To sort out problems you should separate each step. Did you try with a string literal holding the time? Did you verify result of `strftime`? Check your parameters

Comment: What is `localTime` used to determine size of your buffer? Is it a typo and you use `localtime` instead? This is wrong. Please show us real code, not something retyped and only slightly related to your code.

Comment: @Gerhardh There was indeed a typo in my code. I have edited it now.
I have tried to insert from C program using string literal. It works if I write `const char* query = "INSERT INTO time_table(id,time) VALUES(now(),'2019-09-04 10:59:22');"`. But it doesn't work if I write `strcpy(lt,"2019-09-04 10:59:22");`

Comment: I have not much clue about cassandra. In examples I found they used it like this: `cass_statement_bind_string(statement, 0, cass_string_init("abc"));` Did you try to use `cass_string_init()`?

Comment: @Gerhardh I tried with that, but it seems the newer version doesn't support cass_string_init() function.